# how can i get array from matlab function in c#?

Tags: c#, matlab

I call a Matlab function from C# and I need to get an 2x3 array, but in C# I get nothing.

I tried to print the result and the printing is `system object[]` it seems the the result array is empty, despite of in Matlab its not..

```matlab
function X =  check_arr(a,b)
X = [a ,a ,a;b ,b ,b];
end
```

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

    matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\cbencham\Downloads\aa5");

    object[,] result = new object [2,3];

    matlab.Feval("test_arr", 1, out result[1,2], 1, 3);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < result.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(result[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Did you try : X = [[a ;a ;a];[b ;b ;b]];

Comment: the function is called "check_arr" but you call "test_arr"..?

Comment: also, can you try to use out result, instead of: out result[1,2]